# Why does Plotly Cufflinks display "404 Error" on sharing="Secret"?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I'm using Python3 and configured Cufflinks to use `cf.set_config_file(sharing="secret", offline=False)`.

However, when the iframe is embedded in an HTML document, I receive the error:

> 404 Plot twist! There's nothing here...

But the same plot directly implemented with Python without Cufflinks displays fine in HTML. The plot only displays if I'm logged in to Plotly in the same browser I'm using to view the HTML. I'm thinking this is the behavior for `sharing="private"`

Is my `cf.set_config_file()` code incomplete?

[image]